# How to enter an iPhone passcode which contains foreign characters on a Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, icloud, password

For additional security, my Mac is requesting that I enter my iPhone passcode. My iPhone passcode contains non-English letters and other special characters. On my iPhone entering this passcode is done by accessing other keyboards or holding down a key for additional letters.

However, when entering the passcode on my Mac, I have no option for additional keyboards. And holding down a key does not provide additional letters, it just repeats the same letter. Also, I am hindered by being unable to see the passcode (only asterisks) so entering a character mapping code would be difficult, if that is even possible. The only option I see is to select "forgot your passcode?" even though I know my passcode. Is changing my passcode to a more limited character set, my only option?

[image: Mac Request for iPhone Passcode]

Comment: Marcy - could you provide more details about when it's asking for your iPhone passcode (which application, what are you trying to do, etc)?

Comment: I'm not completely sure. I was logging off a family member's account and then logging into my account on one of our macbook pros. This was the first time I had logged into this macbook since it was updated to Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Mac - open System Preferences.

- Keyboard

You can use the Input Sources section to add Unicode Hex Input and enter any of the 120,000 characters in that standard by value. You might also know which type of characters you need and choose a country's input source to get accented or currency characters typical for that region.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed. Although, I managed out of the screen and I haven't triggered it again. Now wondering if that popup is malware.

Comment: @Marcy It is almost certainly legitimate. It's enhanced security of people with two step authentication and iCloud. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280141/iphone-asks-for-mac-password

Comment: I hope your right. I'm using two-factor authentication across multiple devices and don't recall using that screen before. I would have expected to enter a verification code instead.

Comment: Just a follow up @Marcy this “enter the password of the other device” is still how Apple is rolling with sharing keychain items between devices. Before the passwords your iPhone stores will sync with your Mac, the system is checking that you have both the Apple ID and device passwords at your disposal.