# Why do macOS and iOS ask me for the passwords of my other devices?

Tags: macos, ios, password

Usually after a system update, both macOS as well as iOS request that I re-enter my password for my Apple ID. So far, so good. However, I'm always also asked for the passwords of some or all my other Apple devices.

Example:

After the macOS system update, System Preferences displays a red badge. When I open it, it tells me that "some services might not be available" until I re-enter my Apple ID password. After that, I'm asked for the password that unlocks my iPhone, then after that for the password that unlocks my iPad.

I haven't been able to find a documentation of what exactly these other passwords are used for and how. I'd like to know how they are stored (encrypted or hashed?) and where, as well as when they will be used for what purpose?

There is a similar question [iPhone asks for Mac password (or Mac asks for iOS password)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/280141/164512), but it does not ask for a background explanation, just for a way to control it.

---

Note: I'm not using iCloud drive, just in case that matters.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of something, and which password it asks for? After a system update, macOS doesn't ask me for any password, beyond the user account one that is normally asked in any restart.

Comment: @benwiggy Edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: Asking why Apple does things isn’t on topic here. The _what_ is quite clear. Apple is implementing a second factor to trip up the case where another actor someone attempts to enroll your device with your compromised iCloud password without needing an off device local password that it knows is also associated with your account. I’ll link to previous questions that cover both the what and how.

Comment: @bmike It feels a bit unfriendly to immediately close my question. The other answers do not explain how exactly the passwords are used which is what I'm interested in. If you think it is "quite clear", then why don't you provide an answer so I can learn from you? I admit, the word "why" in my heading might be misleading, see the exact question inside.

Comment: I’m voting up your question, this topic  is worth scrutiny and your posting will drive people to the main questions - the title on why and the details don’t seem to be new ground for the site without a substantial edit, so a reversible hold seemed the best choice after I reviewed your question in detail and also the linked questions.